# `yarn semantic-release-cli setup` fails with 404 from github authorizations API

Tags: yarnpkg, semantic-release

Running this command

```sh
yarn semantic-release-cli setup
```

And giving these answers

```
? What is your npm registry? https://registry.yarnpkg.com/
? Which authentication method is this npm registry using? Token based
? What is your npm username? ...
? What is your npm password? [hidden]
? What is your GitHub username? ...
? What is your GitHub password? [hidden]
```

Fails with this error (trimmed for readability), forcing me to repeat the questionnaire in order to retry.

```
StatusCodeError: 404 - {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
    at new StatusCodeError (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\corner-radius\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) 
{
  statusCode: 404,
  error: {
    message: 'Not Found',
    documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest'
  },
  options: {
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/authorizations',
    json: true,
    auth: {
      username: '...',
      password: '...',
      endpoint: 'https://api.github.com',
      user: '...',
      pass: '...'
    },
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'semantic-release' },
    body: { scopes: [Array], note: 'semantic-release-corner-radius-wpmx8n0' },
    callback: [Function: RP$callback],
    transform: undefined,
    simple: true,
    transform2xxOnly: false
  },
  ...
}
```